# Mocking service in nested Mapstruct mapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, mapstruct

Is there some way to mock service A in nested Mapstruct mapper?

I have mapper that I want to test:

```
@Mapper(uses = {
        ForwardMapper.class //here is used nested service A
},
        builder = @Builder(disableBuilder = true),
        componentModel = "spring"
)
public interface AnnouncementMapper {

    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "carrier")
   ...
   ...
    @Mapping(source = ".", target = "forward", qualifiedByName = "ForwardMapper")
    Schedule mapForSchedule(Announcement announcement);
```

When mapping to `forward` I use `ForwardMapper` and inside this mapper there is service A that I want to mock to return some true boolean response in some method. But in `ForwardMapper` my service A is no longer a mock!

My test:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
@AutoConfigureObservability(tracing = false)
class Mapper extends Specification {

    private AService serviceA = Mock()

    @Autowired
    Mapper mapper

def "map announcement to some other announcement"() {
        given:
1 * ServiceA.isEnabled(Value.A) >> true

when:
        def result = mapper.map(announcement)
```

ForwardMapper is a Spring bean with injected ServiceA

Comment: tried @MockBean?

Comment: Yes, the same problem

Comment: The solution is @SpringBean! But thanks to give me a tip!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is (I use Spock in my tests):

```
@SpringBean
private ServiceA serviceA= Mock()
```